# How do I place my algorithms side by side and centered?

Tags: formatting, algorithms, thesis, algorithmic

I'm finalizing my dissertation and am struggling to get these algorithms to display correctly...
I'm new to writing pseudocode in LaTeX too so any recommendations are VERY welcome.
[image: What the code below generates...]

```
\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Thistlethwaite's IDDFS}\label{algorithm:iddfsalgorithm}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{searchAllAtDepth}{search depth}
            \State{Initialise Cloned Cube Object using 3D Cube as reference}
            \If{$depth = 1$}
                \For{every move available in the current solving stage}
                    \State{Reset Cube Object and store to temporary cube variable}
                    \State{Apply move to cube}
                    \If{\Call{prune}{method, cube, depth, solving stage}} \Comment{Checks if the current cube state is worth pursuing further solutions for}
                        \State{Skip the current loop iteration}
                    \EndIf
                    \If{\Call{stage}{current cube state}} 
                    % \Comment{If the current cube state fulfils the current solving stage requirements, append the accumulated moves to the overall solution}
                        \State{\Call{appendSolution}{move}}
                    \EndIf
                \EndFor
            \Else
                \State{\Call{Search}{move prefix, search depth}} 
                % \Comment{Figures out the next move to add to the prefix}
            \EndIf
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}

\hfill

\begin{minipage}{0.46\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Main Recursive Search Method for IDDFS}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{Search}{Move prefix, search depth}
            \State{Initialise fresh cube object}
            \State{Apply the move prefix to the cube}
            \If{\Call{prune}{method, cube, depth, solving stage}}
                \State{\Return}
            \EndIf
            \If{$depth = 0$}
                \If{\Call{Stage}{current cube state}}
                    \State{Append moves to solution}
                    \State{\Return}
                \EndIf
            \Else
                \For{every move available in current solving stage}
                
                    \Call{Search}{move prefix + move, current depth -1}
                    \State{Increment nodes value}
                \EndFor
            \EndIf
        \EndFunction
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
```

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I remember, `minipage` environments will only be displayed next to each other, if there is no empty lines between the two environments, as they are otherwise disconnected. Have you tried removing the two empty lines and the `\hfill`?

Comment: I did that and it works. Also I had to wrap both minipages with ```\begin{centering} and \end{centering}```

Comment: I just tried it myself to make sure and apparently you can leave the `\hfill` there for alignment if you like.

Comment: Even better! It evenly spaces out the algorithms. This is perfect. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the entire dual-algorithm construction inside a `figure` (so that it can float they way it's meant to) and then use `minipage`s with a non-floating `algorithm` (via the `[H]` float specifier) to contain them within the `figure`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \centering
      \caption{Thistlethwaite's IDDFS}\label{algorithm:iddfsalgorithm}
      \footnotesize
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{searchAllAtDepth}{search depth}
          \State{Initialise Cloned Cube Object using 3D Cube as reference}
          \If{$depth = 1$}
            \For{every move available in the current solving stage}
              \State{Reset Cube Object and store to temporary cube variable}
              \State{Apply move to cube}
              \If{\Call{prune}{method, cube, depth, solving stage}} \Comment{Checks if the current cube state is worth pursuing further solutions for}
                \State{Skip the current loop iteration}
              \EndIf
              \If{\Call{stage}{current cube state}} 
                % \Comment{If the current cube state fulfils the current solving stage requirements, append the accumulated moves to the overall solution}
                \State{\Call{appendSolution}{move}}
              \EndIf
            \EndFor
          \Else
            \State{\Call{Search}{move prefix, search depth}} 
            % \Comment{Figures out the next move to add to the prefix}
          \EndIf
        \EndFunction
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
      \centering
      \caption{Main Recursive Search Method for IDDFS}
      \footnotesize
      \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Function{Search}{Move prefix, search depth}
          \State{Initialise fresh cube object}
          \State{Apply the move prefix to the cube}
          \If{\Call{prune}{method, cube, depth, solving stage}}
            \State{\Return}
          \EndIf
          \If{$depth = 0$}
            \If{\Call{Stage}{current cube state}}
              \State{Append moves to solution}
              \State{\Return}
            \EndIf
          \Else
            \For{every move available in current solving stage}
              \Call{Search}{move prefix + move, current depth -1}
              \State{Increment nodes value}
            \EndFor
          \EndIf
        \EndFunction
      \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Remove the empty line between `minipage`s so they fit on the same line, otherwise TeX inserts a paragraph gap.